# Retrofit Simplexml adds classname t request

Tags: android, xml, soap, retrofit2, simple-framework

I'm trying to make a call with retrofit and simplexml. It does work but the classname is added to the request.

The classes:

```
    public class CheckVersionBody extends BaseRequestBody{

    @Element(name = "VersiyonKontrolGenel")
    @Namespace(reference = "http://asdasdasdasd.com/")
    private VersionControlGeneral versionControlGeneral;

    public CheckVersionBody(Object requestBody) {
        super(requestBody);
        this.versionControlGeneral = (VersionControlGeneral) requestBody;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BaseRequestBody<T> {

    @Namespace(reference = "http://asdasdasdasd.com/")
    private T requestBody;

    public BaseRequestBody(T requestBody) {
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }
}
```

---

The request stuff is:

```
<v:Body class="com.application.testapplication.networking.models.CheckVersionBody">
```

and, then the body etc.

How do i get rid of the classname??